# Package djinni has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration

Tags: javascript, android, c++, react-native, djinni

I have djinni installed in my react native project.
I try to run my react native project, but i got this warning in my terminal

```
Package djinni has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration.
```

after that i got this error.

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
24 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 22 up-to-date

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set 

up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/pandusudo/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/pandusudo/Public/mobile-je/android/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/pandusudo/Public/mobile-je/android/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/home/pandusudo/Public/mobile-je/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/pandusudo/Public/mobile-je/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib /home/pandusudo/Public/mobile-je/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/libhelloworld.so}
  [x86] SharedLibrary  : libhelloworld.so

  src/main/jni/../../../../../djinni/jni/NativeHelloWorld.cpp:26: error: undefined reference to 'helloworld::HelloWorld::create()'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: *** [/home/pandusudo/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-binary.mk:725: /home/pandusudo/Public/mobile-je/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/libhelloworld.so] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```